# changeCursor crash when use using SimplecursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have been stuck this issue for 2 days.
I have a Custom SimpleCursorAdapter named **Mail_Content_SimpleCursor** and in my MainActivity have these codes:

```
private Mail_Content_SimpleCursor mail_content_cusor;
private Cursor mail_cursor;
 ListView Mail_contents;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
Mail_contents = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mail_list_view_item);
mail_cursor = mDB.getMailData("gmail@gmail.com"); // Cursor query read recods from database
        startManagingCursor(mail_cursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{"mail_From","mail_Subject","mail_Content"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.mail_list_from,R.id.mail_list_subject,R.id.mail_list_content};
        mail_content_cusor = new Mail_Content_SimpleCursor(this, R.layout.main_mail_list_item, mail_cursor, from, to);
Mail_contents.setAdapter(mail_content_cusor);

}
```

And then, I want to change cursor to get other records with other condition with a function

```
public void change(){
    mail_cursor = mDB.getMailData("yahoo@gmail.com"); // change where clause in query
    startManagingCursor(mail_cursor);
    mail_content_cusor.changeCursor(mail_cursor);
}
```

But changeCursor function make my app crash with this error

```
09-22 14:07:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(31931): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT * FROM mail_contents WHERE mail_user='gmail@gmail.com')
```

Comment: also show Mail_Content_SimpleCursor class code

Comment: How about content providers an cursor loaders?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [swapCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#swapCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) instead .

According To Documentation :

SwapCursor : Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor. Unlike changeCursor(Cursor), the returned old Cursor is not closed.

Comment: Hi. I solved this problem.
Just call  stopManagingCursor(mail_cursor) before changeCursor